# How to set file usage on drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

How do I set the file usage on Drupal 8? How can I use the following methods?

- `file_usage_add()`
- `file_usage_delete()`
- `file_usage_list()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use these methods in Drupal 8:

1. File usage add: `\Drupal::service('file.usage')->add`
2. File usage delete: `\Drupal::service('file.usage')->delete`
3. File usage list: `\Drupal::service('file.usage')->listUsage`