# Cannot install "Remove Unused Files" for Drupal

Tags: composer-php, drush, drupal-9

Instructions for https://www.drupal.org/project/remove_unused_files from @zealialize is to install via composer;
**composer require 'drupal/remove_unused_files:^1.0@beta'**
Getting this;

> -bash-4.2$ composer require -W 'drupal/remove_unused_files:^1.0@beta' ./composer.json has been updated Running composer update
> drupal/remove_unused_files --with-all-dependencies Loading composer
> repositories with package information Updating dependencies Your
> requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
> - drupal/remove_unused_files[1.0.0-beta1, ..., 1.0.0-beta2] require drush/drush ^9.0 -> found drush/drush[9.0.0, ..., 9.7.3] but
> it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^10.6).
> - Root composer.json requires drupal/remove_unused_files ^1.0@beta -> satisfiable by drupal/remove_unused_files[1.0.0-beta1, 1.0.0-beta2].
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to
> their original content.

Does this mean I have to revert drush to version 9.0 in order to install "unused_files" extension?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, or ask the maintainer to remove the composer.json, it's not necessary and does only harm. https://git.drupalcode.org/project/remove_unused_files/-/blob/master/composer.json#L24

Comment: You could of course for now also clone the module yourself and put it into the custom modules folder. Then you can use it.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149554/permanently-delete-unused-orphaned-files-in-drupal-8/55462484#55462484